# How to manually install software/plugin to Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded a RAR file from the following location, to be (manually) installed to Eclipse (Helios). How can I perform the manual installation?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsesql/files/SQL%20Explorer%20RCP%20%28exc%20JRE%29/3.6.1/sqlexplorer_rcp-3.6.1.macosx.cocoa.x86.tgz/download

Comment: There's a comment that the accepted solution no longer applies to current versions of Eclipse, so reopening the question would be valuable. I am trying to set up an automated testing environment and non-interactive updates for Eclipse is particularly important to the success of this project.  The question does skirt the line between administration and programming, but pertains to a task that programmers may find themselves strapped with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From their website (http://www.sqlexplorer.org/):

> Eclipse Plugin
>
> Download
>
> Download the Eclipse SQL Explorer plugin and extract the zip file in your eclipse directory (requires Eclipse 3.3 or better).
>   After restarting eclipse with the -clean option, a new SQL Explorer perspective should be available.
>
> Eclipse Update Site
>
> You can install and update Eclipse SQL Explorer via the eclipse update mechanism. The update site for Eclipse SQL Explorer is http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/

I always go for the update site option if they present it, it's easier and lets you do updates easily. To use the update mechanism just select *Help > Insall New Software...* then enter the update site, press *Add* and go through the wizard.

Comment: Just a note: the sqlexplorer.org information about extracting the zip file in your eclipse directory is `incorrect`.  You can no longer do that (as of 3.4 it won't work reliably).  "Install New Software" or "dropins" is the correct way.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of putting it directly into the plugins directory, it's better to use the dropins directory as this was created just for this purpose. Have a look here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Dropins

For sqlexplorer: do not download the full RCP version (as your link does), this one is standalone. Get this one instead: http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsesql/files/SQL%20Explorer%20Plugin/3.6.1/sqlexplorer_plugin-3.6.1_SR2.zip/download

Extract this to $eclipse_home$\dropins\sqlexplorer and restart Eclipse.

BUT: Using the SqlExplorer Update Site (http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/) would be an even better option (Help>Install new Software)

Answer (score 9):

I have tried the installation with the explanation about the [dropins folder](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Dropins) and had to tweak it like that:

1. Unzip the distribution into your eclipse installation directory under the folder dropins. Your structure should be:

   > ```
   > eclipse/
   >   dropins/
   >     eclipse/
   >       features/
   >       plugins/
   > ```
2. Remove all other files and directories. There is some missing piece (file `contents.xml`), so that the distribution is no real p2 repository which leads to an error. The directories `plugins` and `features` are sufficient.
3. Restart your eclipse (I have done it with option `-clean`, not sure if that is necessary).
4. SQLExplorer is then installed and visible in the help, in different menus and with a new perspective.

I even was able to use it to have a look at my SQLite3 database of a rails3 application. Wow!! So I will give it a try.

Comment: This project layout only applies if you didn't use the eclipse installer.

Comment: Which was release in the new version (4.5) in June 2015. See the date of my answer :-)