# Adding new feature to exported RCP product

Tags: svn, version-control, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, cvs

I have developed an eclipse RCP product which has project explorer where we can create projects. I wanted to provide the plug n play feature to add repositories like SVN, CVS, etc in order to save the projects in repositories. For which I have added the menu item 'team' to my popup menu.

[Team menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSdF4.png)

Also I have added all the SVN related jars to dependencies in product configuration file. I have exported the build using the option "Eclipse Product Export Wizard" in .product file. I am able to connect to SVN repository.

I do not want to provide SVN jars along with my product as they are from third party. So after exporting the product i have placed the SVN related jars inside the plugins folder and restarted the application, but I am not able to see the SVN repository available under menu item Team-->Share Project.

I am not able to figure out why the product is not able to detect the extra plugins and update the configurations like eclipse.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757391/how-to-manually-install-software-plugin-to-eclipse-ide. However, if you are using open-source libraries for working with SVN, you should have no problem including those jars: just respect the license!